# How to get nested array from flatten map with annotations

Tags: arrays, typescript, algorithm

I have a json as the below, annotation the nest and corresponding values.

```json
{
  '0': '0',
  '1': '1',
  '2-0': '2-0',
  '2-1': '2-1',
  '3-0': '3-0',
  '3-1-0': '3-1-0',
  '3-1-1': '3-1-1',
  '3-2': '3-2'
}
```

Then, I try to retrieve a nested array like the below.

```json
[
  '0',
  '1',
  [
    '2-0',
    '2-1'
  ],
  [
    '3-0',
    [
      '3-1-0',
      '3-1-1'
    ],
    '3-2',
]
```

Do you have any ideas to achieve this.

I prefer TypeScript (or JavaScript) but any other languages are also welcome.

Comment: It can be constructed by a DFS on keys hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var input = {
    '0': '0',
    '1': '1',
    '2-0': '2-0',
    '2-1': '2-1',
    '3-0': '3-0',
    '3-1-0': '3-1-0',
    '3-1-1': '3-1-1',
    '3-2': '3-2'
}

var result = Object.keys(input).map(key => ({
            key,
            value: input[key]
        })).reduce((accum, item) => {
            var keys = item.value.split("-");
            var last = accum;
            keys.forEach((key, index) => {
                if (index === keys.length - 1) {
                    last[key] = item.value;
                } else {
                    if (!last[key]) {
                        last[key] = [];
                    }
                }
                last = last[key];
            });
            return accum;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```